# Make Outlook stop trying to connect to server after import

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

I have a client who had a Godaddy/secureserver email account, and several office computers on Outlook connecting to it through a Microsoft Server.  She was having issues with some emails not coming through to Outlook (but you could go into webmail and see them coming to the server).  The guy who had set up her server was no longer around, and I'm not experienced with exchange server settings, so just told her to not have Outlook go through the server but connect directly to secureserver.

So I backed everything up as .pst, totally deleted everything else from Outlook, starting it fresh, and then imported the .pst.  But now all this weird stuff is happening with emails not sending, emails showing up and then disappearing, and the one consistent thing I see happening is an attempt to connect to the exchange server, which is baffling me.  Is something embedded in the .pst telling it to connect to the old server?  If so, how do I save her (thousands and thousands of) emails organized in dozens of folders without bringing back in the exchange settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm you that there's nothing in the PST referencing her old exchange server. The only thing that I can think of is that all the recipients (including sender) email address format, when exporting emails to a PST, are still in the format X500 instead of SMTP. So if you export things to the pst and use this pst outside of this particular exchange server you will not be able to reply or keep track of existing conversations.

I suggest you wipe out all email profiles in Control Panel -> Mail, restart computer and create a new email profile if you did not tried that already

Comment: Great--I especially appreciate the suggestion, which made the difference!